# Ubuntu 21.10: How to stop windows from opening up maximized

Tags: 21.10

After upgrading to Ubuntu 21.10, most new windows are always opening maximized. E.g. any file manager window, the text editor, etc.

Is there any way to revert this setting?

Comment: Un-maximize then close them. Next time they should open as expected.

Comment: They don't, I wouldn't have asked if that happened ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The window manager of Ubuntu desktop has a feature where large windows are automatically maximized. To turn that behaviour off, run the following command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter auto-maximize false
```

Comment: Also can get at this in the Dconf editor, either searching on "mutter", or navigate to: `org > gnome > mutter`, "auto-maximize", toggle off. (This is in 22.04.)

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround: During the Ubuntu login screen after booting the PC, I select first my user name, then in the lower right corner the gear icon and select "Ubuntu on xorg" or something.

After that, windows work correctly again. This also happens to fix some other issues, like "raise on hover" not working correctly.

Comment: So what you have done is change the DE to xorg.